# Dockerized NextCloud installation: 404 page not found

Tags: docker-compose, http-status-code-404, nextcloud

I have installed NextCloud with docker-compose on a new server. The  docker-compose.yml file ran successfully on another server. However, I receive an error message

`404 page not found`

when opening the site in a browser.

Here is the output of docker logs.

```
docker logs 9730d90679df
Initializing nextcloud 25.0.3.2 ...
New nextcloud instance
Installing with MySQL database
Starting nextcloud installation
Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Trace: #0 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/ConnectionAdapter.php(69): OC\DB\Exceptions\DbalException::wrap(Object(Doctrine\DBAL\Exception))
#1 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(59): OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...')
#2 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(39): OC\DB\MySqlTools->isMariaDBWithLargePrefix(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#3 /var/www/html/lib/private/Setup/MySQL.php(47): OC\DB\MySqlTools->supports4ByteCharset(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#4 /var/www/html/lib/private/Setup.php(353): OC\Setup\MySQL->setupDatabase('adminuser')
#5 /var/www/html/core/Command/Maintenance/Install.php(105): OC\Setup->install(Array)
#6 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#7 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#8 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#9 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/lib/private/Console/Application.php(213): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/console.php(100): OC\Console\Application->run()
#12 /var/www/html/occ(11): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')
#13 {main}

Previous: Doctrine\DBAL\Exception: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occurred in the driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
Trace: #0 /var/www/html/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(1519): OC\DB\Connection->connect()
#1 /var/www/html/3rdparty/doctrine/dbal/src/Connection.php(1041): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->getWrappedConnection()
#2 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/Connection.php(261): Doctrine\DBAL\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...', Array, Array, NULL)
#3 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/ConnectionAdapter.php(66): OC\DB\Connection->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...', Array, Array)
#4 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(59): OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter->executeQuery('SELECT VERSION(...')
#5 /var/www/html/lib/private/DB/MySqlTools.php(39): OC\DB\MySqlTools->isMariaDBWithLargePrefix(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#6 /var/www/html/lib/private/Setup/MySQL.php(47): OC\DB\MySqlTools->supports4ByteCharset(Object(OC\DB\ConnectionAdapter))
#7 /var/www/html/lib/private/Setup.php(353): OC\Setup\MySQL->setupDatabase('adminuser')
#8 /var/www/html/core/Command/Maintenance/Install.php(105): OC\Setup->install(Array)
#9 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#10 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#11 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(OC\Core\Command\Maintenance\Install), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#12 /var/www/html/3rdparty/symfony/console/Application.php(149): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 /var/www/html/lib/private/Console/Application.php(213): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#14 /var/www/html/console.php(100): OC\Console\Application->run()
#15 /var/www/html/occ(11): require_once('/var/www/html/c...')
#16 {main}
Retrying install...
Nextcloud was successfully installed
Setting trusted domains…
System config value trusted_domains => 1 set to string MYDOMAINNAME
Initializing finished
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.19.0.5. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Wed Feb 22 11:39:13.166800 2023] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.54 (Debian) PHP/8.1.15 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 22 11:39:13.166950 2023] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

Any idea how to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have used a wrong version specification of traefik, that is, the traefik syntax to specify the traefik labels that I have used in the docker-compose file was according to traefik vs2 but I have pulled a newer version of traefik. So the middleware of traefik was not correctly created and requests from port 443 was not sent to nextcloud.